# SpreadsheetGear Custom functions descriptions

Tags: spreadsheetgear

Could SpreadsheetGear set descriptions for custom functions? 
Like Excel has descriptions for every argument in standard functions. Like Xll add-in can do it. 
In the constructor of SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.Function I see only Function name and argument types.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear does not provide a way to add function descriptions or argument descriptions to your own custom functions.

FYI: I work for SpreadsheetGear and we do take requests for things like this.  You're welcome to [contact us directly](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/company/contact.aspx) so we can add your contact information to this feature request.  I suppose we might add such a feature for our custom functions after we add an "IntelliSense"/Formula-Builder sort of feature for our WorkbookView/FormulaBar controls.